# How can you create a function that selects numbers based on their probability?

Tags: c++

Suppose we have a map of numbers to probabilities. Is there a way to create a function that selects a key based on it's probability? So suppose the map contains two values, 2->0.55 and 3->0.66. When I call this function I want the probabilities to determine how often the number is called, so since 3 has probability 66% it will be called more often than 2 (and exactly by it's probability value).

Any ideas?

Comment: How does this work exactly? 66% + 55% != 100%.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: But that's just aesthetics! The method will likely stay the same if you call them *weights* instead of *probabilites* (which they cannot be).

Comment: @BenjaminBannier The asker says that it's a probability and each value should be chosen with that probability, as though 2 should be chosen with probability 0.55 and 3 with probability 0.66. If they were weights, the probabilities would be different, so it's important for them to say what they actually want.

Comment: It's possible that they mean that 2 should be chosen with probability 0.55 or not chosen, and 3 should be chosen with probability 0.66 or not chosen, so it's possible to choose both or neither.

Answer (score 4):

If what you actually want is to treat these "probabilities" as weights, you can use a [`std::discrete_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution):

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::discrete_distribution<> d({0.55, 0.66});
```

Then when you call `d(gen)`, you'll get value 0 with weight 0.55 and value 1 with weight 0.66. This of course means that the *probability* of getting 0 is actually `0.55/(0.55+0.66) = 0.45`, and the probability of getting 1 is therefore `1 - 0.45 = 0.55`.

You then just need to map from `0` to `2` and from `1` to `3`.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially you need to keep the list of probabilities and their sum.

Generate a random number in the range `0 <= number < sum` (using [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) or [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution), depending on the type).

Iterate through the list adding up the values until you reach a value greater than or equal to your generated value.

The number you're currently at is the randomly selected one.

If you have a lot of values there are a few tricks you can use to speed this up such as sorting the list largest values first and potentially even having a skip list type of structure that allows you to jump to certain probability totals in the list. Generally that sort of thing isn't needed though and if you do do it you have to be very careful not to get it wrong and skew the results.

Comment: Additional note: If the probabilities (or weights) are *fixed* at some point during initialization, we can precompute a prefix sum (i.e. for each item we determine the sum of all weights of items prior to it); then we can simply access it with binary search and don't need to sum up values.

Comment: [std::discrete_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) does this automatically.

Comment: Nice, I knew the algorithm but not the C++ libraries well enough to make a recommendation. Upvoted your answer @sftrabbit

Comment: @TimB To be honest, the standard descriptions of these distributions are not exactly easy to read. I had to use cppreference.com to know it was the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the probabilities as "weights" and add them all up to get the total weight *W*. Generate a random floating-point number *x* between 0 and *W*. If 0 <= *x* < *W1* (where *W1* is the weight of the first choice), choose the first number. If *W1* <= x < *W1 + W2*, choose the second number, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Given an array of elements with their probability `{a=>0.1, b=>0.2, c=>0.3, d=>0.4}'

The total probability must be 1! Then create an array which adds up the probabilities like this `{a=>0.1, b=>0.3, c=>0.6, d=>1}`. Now generate a random number between 0 and 1.
And check if its smaller 0.1 select `a`, if its just smaller 0.3 select `b` and so on!

Comment: You can remove the restriction that the probabilities must add up to 1 by generating the random number between 0 and *W* where *W* is the sum of the "probabilities" (weights).

Comment: True but if you want the probabilities for one element it must add up to one! That does not mean that you can't always generate this for finite elements!